# Vertically center having a floating sibling element

Tags: html, css

I need to vertically center a div, adjacent to a floating div.

```css
.pic {float: left; width: 50%; border: 1px solid red;}
.description {border: 1px dotted green;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic1<br>this is a big pic</div>
    <div class="description">one</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic2<br>this<br> is a pic2<br>this is another big pic</div>
    <div class="description">this is a multiline text example, yes, multiline one</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    etc...
  </figure>
</div>
```

Is there a way to center the `description` *without* modifying (the CSS or HTML of) the:

a) the floatting `.pic`
b) the `.description` parent elements?

I need only *the text* to be
- centered
- to the right of the ".pic"

the green border behavior I don't care about...

Also, to be compatible with *IE11*

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear to me... you want the "two" description div to be centered next to the entire "pic2" `.pic` div? Where do you want the "etc" div?

Comment: each description centered on the right of its own picture

Comment: No, it's not possible to do this if you are only able to modify the CSS of the `.description` div. If modifying the `.container` div will break your code somehow, then you need to include more code and information in the question, so that we can provide an answer that does what you want *and* accounts for this extra constraint.

Comment: as I already said, the "not possible" is also an answer. I know that if the display of containers is modified I break the display of another elements, but I am not able to provide a live example, as the real example is too complex to reproduce and I have no time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.pic {float: left; width: 50%; border: 1px solid red;}
.description {border: 1px dotted green;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic1<br>this is a big pic</div>
    <div class="description">one</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic2<br>this<br> is a pic2<br>this is another big pic</div>
    <div class="description">two</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    etc...
  </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps make it clear you mean the figures are the containers and not the div that literally has the class `container`.

Comment: I didn't say "container" I wrote "containers" ;)

Comment: There could easily be multiple `div.container` elements in your overall design.

Comment: If by "containers" you mean `figures` why not just say so. and what do you mean by "not modify".

Comment: it would be `.container`s. But let me see if I can apply your variant to my case... maybe I could apply it... is compatible with IE11

Comment: @Serge James' HTML looks identical to the HTML in the question... what do you mean by "modified the containers"?

Comment: by not modify I mean do not change the containers CSS or HTML (if not it will break another logic/display of the application)

Comment: updated the OP to clarify the question. No, your solution unfortunately does not fit my case (the display flex broke the display of other elements)

Comment: @Serge So you want us to fix your css without touching the css?  Your question makes no sense - it's not possible if you are not allowed to change any css

Comment: @Pete don't exaggerate, you can modify the css of the description field.

Comment: @Serge I'm not: *by not modify I mean do not change the containers CSS or HTML* so what can we do?

Comment: of the **parent** elements

Comment: @Serge Well you didn't write that did you? Stop drip feeding requirements

Comment: @Pete, I wrote it, be more attentive.

Comment: @Serge Haha you wrote it in an edit to the main question that didn't show up until after I made my comment (in which I was referencing your comment above). well done, being rude is surely the way to get more help

Comment: This is not possible based on your restrictions. There is NO CSS method of aligning floated elements with one another. I suggest you re-think your requirements.

Comment: @Pete, please review my edit to see what exactly was edited.

Comment: @Paulie_D, the `.description` is not a floated element. the `parent` is not a floated element...

Comment: also, in this solution, the `wrap` does not allow the *multiline* text in the `.description`... or, if is eliminated the 50% of the `.pic` is not respected, probably this broke my displaying, I have multiline text in the description.

Comment: please try in the description to put "this is a multiline text example, yes, multiline one"

Comment: The pic is a floated element.

Comment: after testing, I arrived to manage the multiline.... my answer bellow, so, I can accept this answer (using the fixes from my answer). thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

finally, testing with multiline texts, I could adapt the James answer to my needs. this is something like this

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.pic {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.description {
  border: 1px dotted green;
  max-width: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic1<br>this is a big pic</div>
    <div class="description">one</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <div class="pic">pic2<br>this<br> is a pic2<br>this is another big pic</div>
    <div class="description">two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two two twotwo two two twotwo twotwo twotwo two</div>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    etc..
  </figure>
</div>
```